# Incorrect output from VBA Excel code

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
    Case "L"
     If UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "L/M" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 3.5



     ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LM$" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 3.5

ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "LM" Then
 If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
            If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 2) + 3.5
            Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 2) + 0.35
           End If
            End If


 If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 5, 1)) Then
            If Mid(Dn, 5, 1) = "0" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 3.5
            Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 0.35
            End If
            End If


    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "L$" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 3, 2)) + 2

     ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LOW" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LO-" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 6)) = "LO MID" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 7, 3)) + 3.5



    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LO " Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 2

    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 5)) Like "L###S" Then
      If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
             Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 2
        Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 0.2
        End If
        End If
     '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
    'ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 1)) = "L" Then
            'Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 2
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
            'ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) Then
            'Dn.Offset(, 1) = IIf(Mid(Dn, 3, 1) = 0, Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 2)) + 2, Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 2)) + 0.2)

            'ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) Then
            'Dn.Offset(, 1) = IIf(IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1) + Mid(Dn, 3, 1)), Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 2, Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) + 0.2)
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
       ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 5)) Like "L###S" Then
      If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
             Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 2
        Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 0.2
        End If
        End If


    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 4)) Like "L##S" Then
      If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 3, 1) = "0" Then
             Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 2
        Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 0.2
        End If
        End If
        End If


      If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) Then
             Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 2)) + 0.2
     End If

       'ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 4)) Like "L###" Then
           ' Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 0.2
    ' End If
```

my current output from the code is as follows:

```
*L111 --> 111.2
*L100 --> 100.2
*L100S --> 100.2
*L10S --> 12.2
*L12S --> 12.2
```

**Desired output to be as follow:**

```
*L111 --> 111.2
*L100 --> 100.2
*L100S --> 100
*L10S --> 12
*L12S --> 12.2
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You didn't provide all of the code. Your output sample doesn't match with the code you provided.

Comment: @DanielCook, thank you for your response, apology for the incomplete information. The code is quite long and complex, hence i have only pasted the case L variables.  I hope this clarifies the problem. any help and guidance would be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the final If/Then is adding 0.2 to all of your five inputs, which it should: `IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1))` is true for all of your inputs.

This code would likely benefit (in readability, debugging, etc) from using a Select Case statement, rather than all of your Ifs and ElseIfs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, yes your right, the final if statement was over riding the other if conditions, so i used the like function to solve my problem.  Thank once again for your time and help.

Comment: if you want to thank him - you should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you above, for your suggestion and help, but I manage to work out an solution to my own problem.

```
Case "L"
     If UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "L/M" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 3.5

     ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LM$" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 3.5

ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "LM" Then
 If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
            If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 2) + 3.5
            Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 2) + 0.35
           End If
            End If


 If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 5, 1)) Then
            If Mid(Dn, 5, 1) = "0" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 3.5
            Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 0.35
            End If
            End If


    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "L$" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 3, 2)) + 2

     ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LOW" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LO-" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 2
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 6)) = "LO MID" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 7, 3)) + 3.5

    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LO " Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 2

    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 5)) Like "L###S" Then
      If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
             Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 2
        Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 0.2

        End If
        End If

   ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 4)) Like "L##S" Then
      If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 3, 1) = "0" Then
           Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 2
       Else
          Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 0.2
       End If
        End If


   ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 4)) Like "L###" Then
      If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
             Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 0.2
        Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 0.2

        End If
        End If

   ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) Like "L##" Then
      If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 3, 1) = "0" Then
           Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 0.2
       Else
          Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 0.2
       End If
       End If

    End If
```